# iOS - Convert IFNULL(...) JSON key into object attribute

Tags: ios, json, jsonmodel, pocket

I'm working with `Pocket` API and getting a user's articles. I use the `JSONModel` library that I found on `GitHub` to make `Article` objects using the attributes that I get from the JSON response. Each `Article` object has a `wordCount` attribute that used to be easily assigned from part of Pocket's API response:

```
"word_count" = 947;
```

But now, for some reason, Pocket changed the way it gives the word count, and now it gives the following:

```
"IFNULL(e.word_count, 0)" = 947;
```

This crashed my app because my `JSONModel` library was expecting each article to have a word_count attribute so it could make it into an `Article` object with a `wordCount` attribute. How do I fix this?

The following is my code for the `Article.h` object setup:

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

@class Article;

@interface Article : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *newsSource;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *givenUrl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *resolvedUrl;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *resolvedTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *excerpt;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary<Optional> *image;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *wordCount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *fullText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *summary;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *itemId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *favorite;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *hasImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *status;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary<Optional> *authors;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *sortId;

+(void)retrieveArticlesWithState:(NSString*)state andFavorite:(NSString *)favorite andOffset:(NSNumber*)offsetInteger successCallback:(void (^)(NSArray*))success errorCallback:(void (^)(NSString*))error;
```

This above code is letting `JSONModel` know what attributes to expect from the JSON response and turn into attributes for each `Article` object.

In my `Article.m` file, I implement the method with the following:

```
+(void)retrieveArticlesWithState:(NSString*)state andFavorite:(NSString *)favorite andOffset:(NSNumber*)offsetInteger successCallback:(void (^)(NSArray*))success errorCallback:(void (^)(NSString*))error
{
    [self letPocketRetrieveArticlesWithState:state andFavorite:favorite andOffset:offsetInteger successCallback:[Article modelListCallback:success] errorCallback:error];
}
```

This method helps me convert attributes like `word_count` to `wordCount`:

```
#pragma mark - helpers

//Built in option for JSONModel to turn things like sort_id into sortId
+(JSONKeyMapper*)keyMapper
{
    return [JSONKeyMapper mapperFromUnderscoreCaseToCamelCase];
}
```

This code helps me consistently convert into multiple `Article` objects to return a list:

```
/*!
 * @brief Helper method to get the same block to consistently turn API response into article models.
 * @param callback A block to call once the article has been parsed from the API response.
 * @return A block to be passed along to API requests for parsing out API responses consistently.
 */
+(void(^)(NSDictionary*))modelListCallback:(void (^)(NSArray*))callback {
    return ^(NSDictionary* json){
        NSError* err = nil;
        NSMutableArray* articles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(NSDictionary* article in [[json objectForKey:@"list"] allValues]) {
            [articles addObject:[[Article alloc] initWithDictionary:article error:&err]];
        }
        callback(articles);
    };
}
```

This is part of the example JSON response that I get:

```
{
    complete = 1;
    error = "<null>";
    list =     {
        1027166096 =         {
            "IFNULL(e.word_count, 0)" = 2930;
            authors =             {
                37936109 =                 {
                    "author_id" = 37936109;
                    "item_id" = 1027166096;
                    name = "Telegraph Reporters";
                    url = "http://www.telegraph.co.uk/authors/telegraph-reporters/";
                };
            };
            excerpt = "In his third year at Oxford, as an undergraduate studying biology and physiology, Oliver Sacks was not yet 20 years old when he first decided to take LSD.";
            favorite = 0;
            "given_title" = "Oliver Sacks' most mind-bending experiment";
...
...
...
```

Comment: can you rephrase what the problem is? and can you include the JSON that crashes your model?

Comment: Sure thing, one sec.

Comment: @MarinTodorov I have updated my post with the code that I'm using and an example of the JSON response that I'm getting.

Comment: The word count part of the JSON response used to be just "word_count" = something but now it's "IFNULL(e.word_count, 0)" for some reason. This is crashing my app because JSONModel keeps giving me the "missing keys: wordCount" error in that it's failing to convert that into an attribute object since Pocket it returning it differently now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this looks like a bug on their side ... "IFNULL(e.word_count, 0)" is an SQL code that should not appear as a key in the JSON response. If you have a way to you should report this bug to them

Comment: I think you're right. I just tried it again and it started giving me the correct "word_count" attribute instead of the one that was crashing my app. I will report this to the Pocket API team just in case it can be a random issue. But for now, I'll just have to mark the `wordCount` attribute as `Optional` just in case this randomly happens again in the future. Thanks!